# Sum of even and odd naturals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

I want to prove that the sum of the first even $k$ natural numbers is $k^2+k$ given that the sum of the first odd $k$ naturals is $k^2$. So, \begin{align*} \underbrace{1+3+5}_{k=3}&=k^2=3^2=9 \\ &\vdots \\ \underbrace{1+3+5+\cdots+(2k-1)}_{k \ terms}&=k^2, n\in\mathbb N \end{align*}
needs to be used to prove that
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{2+4+\cdots+(2k)}_{k \ terms}= k^2+k, n\in\mathbb N
\end{align*}
This would be easier to do for me if I could write this using summation notation, but I can't figure out a way to do this because $k$ isn't an upper limit, but the number of terms. All I can say is that if the given sum is true, then if I add $1$ to every term $k$ times, then every term on the lefthand side would be even and the righthand side would add a $k$ term. Like so, \begin{align*}1+3+\cdots+(2k-1)&=k^2 \\ 1+1+\cdots+1&=k 
\\ \implies 2+4+\cdots+(2k)&=k^2+k\end{align*}

But It feels like this explanation is sort of hand-wavy.

Comment: You mean "the sum of the first $k$ even natural numbers equals $k^2+k$" . The argument at then end is superb , if you replace the $n$ by $k$

Comment: What is the relationship of $n$ to $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $$\sum_{i=1}^k (2i-1)=k^2$$

That is $$\sum_{i=1}^k (2i)-\sum_{i=1}^k1=k^2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^k 2i = k^2+k$$